# MATLAB Error in making movie of 3D surface plots

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

For a project I am numerically solving partial differential equations with matlab. It is one of the first times I am actually using Matlab. To graphically show the results I intend to make a movie of plots progressing through time. For 2 dimensional plots all goes well: making the plots, using `getframe` and saving the movie. However when I expand the case to 3 dimensional plots, and use `surf` instead of `plot`. Matlab gives the following error:

The 'cdata' field of FRAME must not be empty

The surface plots themselves are actually being made and given as output. However, when saving the movie this error occurs. I therefor suspect the problem to be with `getframe`, but so far I have not found a way to solve this. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Here is the part of the code for the plotting

```
for i=1:length(T)
U = E*U+(1/d)*B*(E-I)*(d*b+sfunc(U));
Sol = ones(Ny,Nx);
for i=1:(Ny-1)
    Sol(i,1:(Nx-1)) = U(((Nx-1)*(i-1)+1):((Nx-1)*i));
end
surf(X,Y,Sol);
axis([0,1,0,1,0,3]);
caxis([1,2]);
view([15 45]);
M(i+1)=getframe;
end

fps = (1/10)*length(M);
v = VideoWriter('testfilm2dim.avi');
v.FrameRate = fps;
open(v)
writeVideo(v, M);
close(v)
```

Again, the plots are correct, so there is probably no added value in including the rest of the code.

Comment: Your first problem is that you're changing loop index `i` inside the for loop. Resolve that issue and see if the problem persists.

Comment: as @Delyle said, your  inner loop always ends with `(Ny-1)` therefore you are only filling the `(Ny-1)` entry in your frames struct `M`. thus all the entries before that are empty, and when coming to write the video the error arises. use different index (not `i`) for the inner loop.

Comment: Thanks people. A really silly mistake I see now, but I just could not find it